# Nginx: How to setup multiple virtual hosts (server blocks) on different subdomains?

Tags: nginx, digital-ocean, nginx-config, nginx-location

***EDIT:***

---

Ok, very strange still. It seems that it does not work on my main browser. In incognito browsers or just a completely new chrome window the sites now do work. I guess it has something to do with browser caching?

---

So I am hosting my website on Digital Ocean and I want to host multiple 'websites' on 1 droplet/server. By multiple websites, I mean different subdomains of my main domain. So I want to host `admin.domain.com`, `dev.domain.com` and `test.domain.com` on the same server. I followed [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04) tutorial, but it is not working like expected. Currently, only 1 subdomain of the 3 is working...

**What have I tried so far?**

First of, I created 3 A records in my DNS all pointing to the same server_ip droplet on Digital Ocean.

I've created a different a different folder for each subdomain in the `/var/www` folder, each containing a `html` folder with a simple `index.html` file and some html:

[image: website directiories]

The image above shows my `/var/www` folder.

I then used the following command `sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www`.

Next, I copied the default server block file and used this as the default for a new server block with the following command:

`sudo cp /etc/nginx/sites-available/default /etc/nginx/sites-available/admin.domain.nl`

I changed the contents of the file **in all 3 config files for the 3 subdomains** to the following (obviously changing the `root` to the specific subdomain aswell as the `server_name`):

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/admin.domain.nl/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name admin.domain.nl;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

I then used the following command: `sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/dev.domain.nl /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` 3 times for the 3 different subdomains to 'enable' the server blocks.

This is my sites-enabled folder:

[image: sites enabled]

I've had no syntax errors and thus restarted nginx with: `sudo systemctl restart nginx`.

**The problem**

Now, for some very odd reason I do not understand, ***only*** the `admin.domain.nl` site is working. The other 2 subdomains simply display: `This site can’t be reached`.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

## IN /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
http {

    # ...........................others contents.....................................

    # in bottom
    
    server {
        listen 80;
        root /var/www/html/cmp/api;
        server_name "cmpapi.localhost";
        index index.html index.php;
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html $uri.php =404;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        root /var/www/html/cmp/frontend;
        server_name "cmp.localhost";
        index index.html index.php;
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html $uri.php =404;
        }
    }

}
```

1. Here my project name is cmp. here 2 project

   1. one is react frontend
   2. another is laravel api project
2. Here 2 folder created in

   1. /var/www/html/cmp/api

      - This assigned to http://cmpapi.localhost (server_name)
   2. /var/www/html/cmp/frontend

      - This assigned to http://cmp.localhost (server_name)

## cmd

```
sudo find /var/www/html/cmp/frontend/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;  
sudo find /var/www/html/cmp/frontend/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;  

sudo find /var/www/html/cmp/api/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
sudo find /var/www/html/cmp/api/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;  

systemctl reload nginx
```

## Browser

- http://cmpapi.localhost
- http://cmp.localhost